# gvim some tag works OK but some tag not found

Tags: vim, tags

I have a simple vim tag file:

```
pin1 HELLO.pat call cursor(18,1);"
pin2 HELLO.pat call cursor(18,2);"
...
pin20 HELLO.pat call cursor(18,20);"
```

so I can use :tag pinX jump to cursor position (18,X).  This works fine in CentOS 7 and CentOS 8.  But strange behavior happened when I use this tag file in Win10.

Only pin1, pin2 ... pin8 work.
:tag pin9, tag pin10 ... will cause E426, tag not found !!!

If I use auto-complete, :tag + , pin1, pin2 ... pin20 will show up one by one without problem.

Any suggestion ??

KC

Answer (score 1):

You will need to define how your tags are sorted by adding a line like this to the top of your tag file:

```
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED       1       /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
```

And if it's sorted, then you'll need to respect that `pat10` comes before `pat2`.

I'm not to sure, but I would guess the reason the same file works on one machine and not the other is based on how your `:h 'tagcase` etc are setup.